# Does weblogic 10.3.6 supports Sybase version 15.7.x officially?

Tags: weblogic, sybase, weblogic-10.x, weblogic11g, sybase-ase15

Does anybody knows how to verify the supported versions of Sybase by a particular version of Oracle Weblogic Application server?

We are using Oracle Weblogic Server **11g(10.3.6)** on a solaris box. We are connecting to Sybase Database using jConn jar. We want to upgrade our Sybase version to **15.7 or 16.0**, but we are not able to find any official documentation in the Weblogic site mentioning if a particular version of Sybase is supported by Oracle.

We don't want to move to a version of Sybase which is not officially supported by Oracle for Weblogic version 11g (10.3.6).

Does anybody knows a URL where Oracle mentions the list of Sybase versions that is supported by weblogic 11g(10.3.6) version of weblogic??

Answer (score 0):

According to the Oracle Support website, only Sybase versions 15.0 and 15.5 are supported on WebLogic 10.3.6.

https://community.oracle.com/message/12004808#12004808

and

https://support.oracle.com/epmos/faces/CertifyResults?_afrLoop=215316105296988&searchCtx=st%255EANY%257Cpa%255Epi%255E1057_Oracle%2BWebLogic%2BServer%257Evi%255E22765%257Epln%255EAny%257E%257C&_afrWindowMode=0

[image]

Comment: Thanks Brian for the response. Unfortunately, I am not able to open the URLs which you have mentioned in your post. I am not having permissions to view them. Could you be able to post a screenshot of the documentation for my reference?